# Союзы в начале предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда я работала на телевидении, меня всегда поправляли, если я начинала вопрос интервью с союза "а" или "но". Даже вырезали потом это. С тех пор я этих союзов в начале предложения очень опасаюсь и убираю их где только можно.
Сейчас я делаю письменные интервью, но союза "а" в начале вопроса стараюсь избегать как могу. А ведь так часто хочется спросить: "А как вы думаете..." Даже это предложение у меня началось с союза "а".
Разрешите мои сомнения: насколько и когда уместен союз "а" в начале предложения?

Answer (score 5):

Нежелательность союзов в начале предложения - миф. Союз в начале предложения — одно из средств литературной выразительности.  Кстати, есть правило. Точка ставится перед союзами *и, а, но, однако* и т. п., если они не связывают в одно целое предложения, а начинают собой самостоятельное предложение,  См., например, Володю А. П. Чехова:
На дворе уж восходило солнце, громко пели птицы; слышно было, как в саду шагал садовник и как скрипела его тачка... *А* немного погодя послышалось мычанье коров и звуки пастушеской свирели. Солнечный свет и звуки говорили, что где-то на этом свете есть жизнь чистая, изящная, поэтическая. Но где она? О ней никогда не говорили Володе ни maman, ни все те люди, которые окружали его.
Мой отец — тихий человек, но я не сомневаюсь, что он возьмётся за оружие. ***А*** мать, с её характером, — та безусловно возьмётся за оружие (Фадеев).
Я везде чувствовал связь, соединяющую всё это молодое общество, и с грустью чувствовал, что связь эта как-то обошла меня. Но это было только минутное впечатление
***(Л. Толстой) .***
«А мы правда думали, пропал», сказала она. И не понять было: сожалеет или радуется. ***В. Астафьев, Царь-рыба.*** Правда ведь, папа, смешная сказка? . ***Айтматов, Белый пароход.*** Но он и правда честен и верен  верит, что жив царь Николай, пишет все бумаги по-старому и клянется, что умрет с буквой «ять. ***М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша.***
Я везде чувствовал связь, соединяющую всё это молодое общество, и с грустью чувствовал, что связь эта как-то обошла меня. Но это было только минутное впечатление
***(Л. Толстой) .***

Answer (score 4):

Союзы  А и НО в начале фразы часто встречаются в  речи,   являясь нашими незаменимыми помощниками при делении содержания на отдельные фрагменты, которые мы сопоставляем или противопоставляем друг другу. Это очень важный структурный (присоединительный) элемент при построении  текста, когда нужно обозначить новое  развитие темы или  перейти к другому взгляду на  проблему. Ну вот, к примеру,  как обойтись без присоединительных союзов в следующих вопросах:

― А как вы считаете, Райский заплатит что-нибудь?

― А как вы думаете, ваше превосходительство, в самом ли деле было вавилонское столпотворение, или это только так, одно иносказание

― А что, Илья Петрович, матрас в диванной на кушетке, обитый жёлтым ситцем, не нужен вам?

― А как вы оцениваете наш российский рынок?

― Но как ты находишь мой проект в целом?

― Но зачем, зачем вы приехали?

В то же время присоединительное значение сопоставительно-противительных союзов предполагает использование их преимущественно в художественной или разговорной речи, так для  присоединения в чистом виде характерны спонтанность и добавочный характер сообщения,что вряд ли уместно для делового или научного стиля.

Таким образом, присоединительные предложения с союзами А и НО  необходимы  для  выразительного построения речи, но при этом  употребление этих союзов должно быть оправданным как по семантике, так и по стилю.

Answer (score 2):

> А ведь так часто хочется спросить

Правда любите. Я тоже люблю предложения с А и И начинать. И вообще злоупотребляю И как усилительной частицей. 
Мне кажется, что если уместно и в меру, то можно.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно веке в 12-м (и раньше, и позднее) с такого "а" начиналась почти каждая фраза. Означало такое "а" примерно следующее: "вот что я вам сейчас скажу". Это был живой русский язык. Теперь такое "а" из литературного языка изгоняется. Об этом хорошо рассказывал Зализняк в лекции для школьников "Об истории русского языка". Найдите, почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

У некоторых людей в ситуации спонтанной речи (когда сложно оценить свой монолог в целом, тем более если волнуешься) "а" и "но" становятся словами-паразитами. Особенно "а", ведь его можно тянуть, взяв паузу для размышления. И получается бесконечное "а-а-а". Это очень некрасиво. А если употреблять эти союзы часто, трудно уловить логическую последовательность, текст превращается в бесконечную череду возражений.  Поэтому на телевидении и советовали их избегать. Это всего лишь профессиональная речевая специфика, а не ошибка.

Так, сегодня на всех сайтах писательского мастерства советуют не употреблять деепричастные обороты. А всё потому, что начинающие авторы просто не умеют делать это правильно. У них сплошь и рядом "проезжая мимо станции, слетает шляпа".

А некоторые литредакторы запрещают журналистам употреблять глаголы на -ся (по той же причине). Все эти рекомендации ограниченно-практического свойства.

Comment: >> Так, сегодня на всех сайтах писательского мастерства советуют не употреблять деепричастные обороты. А всё потому, что начинающие авторы просто не умеют делать это правильно. У них сплошь и рядом "проезжая мимо станции, слетает шляпа".

Это не начинающие не умеют, это неграмотные не умеют. Ну, то есть те, которые плохо учились в школе. Писатели, понимаешь...

Comment: Получается, что их большинство, раз возникла необходимость в такой рекомендации.